# Does Android Studio retrieve all data from database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-database

I am using SQLiteOpenHelper database provided by android.

does android studio retrieve all the data from database?

Because even after deleting it the Application is working. 
If yes then how will I know? Because the issue was when I try to add some more value in SQLite database but it was retrieving previous data, and when I rename the database and also in coding that time it was retrieving updated data.

**Here is my SqliteCode:**

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_NAME = "NavyDb13.db";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
private Context mContext = null;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);


    DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    File file = new File(DB_PATH + "NavyDb13.db");
    if (file.exists())
        openDataBase(); // Add this line to fix db.insert can't insert values

   this.mContext = context;
    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
}


public void openDataBase() {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}


public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    try {
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (tempDB != null)
            tempDB.close();
    }
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean isDBExists = checkDataBase();
    if (isDBExists) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            this.close();
        }
    }


}




@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Thank You .

Comment: be specific to your question.. edit your question and add some code. so the people can understand.

Comment: Android Studio doesn't do anything with a database. You only write code there.

Comment: Android studio is a tool for development, it does not handle your databases. So answer is **No**